# Solving a recursion relation: $a_{n+1}=-3a_n+4a_{n-1}+2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm having trouble solving this recursion relation. I believe it's a non-homogeneous one.
Here it is:
$$a_{n+1}=-3a_n+4a_{n-1}+2$$

Really, I am just having trouble with the particular solution.

The initial values are not specified.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the initial values $a_1$ and $a_2$ specified? Or are they arbitrary?

Comment: Try as particular solution $a_n=cn,$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: @Bolt64 No they are not specified.

Comment: No reason to vote to close?  This question seems fine to me~

Answer (score 4):

We have $\displaystyle a_{n+1}+3a_n-4a_{n-1}-2=0$

Let $\displaystyle a_n=b_n+cn$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant

$\displaystyle\implies b_{n+1}+c(n+1)+3\{b_n+cn\}-4\{b_{n-1}+c(n-1)\}-2=0$

$\displaystyle \implies b_{n+1}+3b_n-4b_{n-1}+c+4c-2=0$

We can safely set $\displaystyle c+4c-2=0\iff c=\frac25$ to eliminate the consonant from the recurrence relation

Then use this [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)

Comment: @batch, How about this?

Comment: Good! I see where the numbers come from. I think this is the exact method i learned in class. Thanks mate.

Comment: @batch, My pleasure

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to solve these is with linear algebra:

$$\begin{align}
a_{n + 1}= -3a_n + 4a_{n-1} + 2 \\
a_{n} =     1a_n + 0a_{n-1} + 0 \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_n \\ a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}
 + \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 4 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_n \\ a_{n-1} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 4 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^n
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Although I prefer leaving it like this, you can use jordan decomposition:

$$\begin{cases}
P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -\frac 14 \\ 0 & \frac 52 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -4 \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 
(P\,D\,P^{-1})^n
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 
P\,\begin{bmatrix} 1 & n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & (-4)^n \end{bmatrix}\,P^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
a_n = \frac 1{25}\bigg( a_1\,5\left(1 - (-4)^{n+1}\right) + a_0\,5\left(4 + (-4)^{n+1}\right) + 2(-4)^{n+1} + 10n + 8 \bigg)$$

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that $a_n=a\cdot 1^n=a$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation (without the $2$ in it).

To see what to do put $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ so that $b_{n+1}=-4b_n+2$, which has the particular solution $b_n=\frac 25$. This then gives $a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac 25=a_0+\frac 25\cdot n$ and a particular solution is seen to be $\frac 25\cdot n$.

The root $1$ of the auxiliary equation $x^2=-3x+4$ means that the test function for the particular solution should be $a\cdot n$ rather than just $a$. If the auxiliary equation had a double root $1$ - say the recurrence were $c_{n+1}=2c_n-c_{n-1}+2$ you'd need to use $c\cdot n^2$, because $a\cdot n+b$ is then a solution to the homogeneous part.

Comment: Ah that's it. Thank you! But I still need some more information about the part you multiply 2/5 by n. Where does that come from.

Comment: @batch using $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac 25$ we get $a_1=a_0+\frac 2/5$; then $a_2=a_1+\frac 25=a_0+2\cdot \frac 25$ etc

Answer (score 0):

After the clever suggestion from lab bhattacharjee and using the method he refers to, you should simply arrive to $$b_n=\frac{1}{20} \left((-4)^n ({b_2}-{b_1})+4 (4 {b_1}+{b_2})\right)$$ since the roots of the characteristic equation are $r=1$ and $r=-4$.

Now, back to the original problem, you then have $$a_n=\frac{1}{100} \left((-4)^n (-5 {a_1}+5 {a_2}-2)+80 {a_1}+20 {a_2}+40   n-48\right)$$